# Can't attach transformer to element from another class using konva

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva

I am trying to attach a transformer to an element using findOne and Id, when printing it recognizes both nodes but does not attach it, no error is shown. Below is the concerned function triggered onClick, the nodes are defined in a sibling class and no event listeners are supposed to be triggered on the class where it's defined for it to attach.

By the way, all props are defined on the parent component

below is the concerned conditional statement, the element is within a group which is inside a layer in the parent component:

```
if(this.props.selectedElementsID===this.props.id)
{
    console.log(this.props.layer)
   console.log(this.props.layer.findOne(`#${this.props.id}`).findOne(`#transform${this.props.id}`))
    console.log(this.props.layer.findOne(`#${this.props.id}`).findOne(`#${this.props.id}`))
    this.props.layer.findOne(`#${this.props.id}`).findOne(`#transform${this.props.id}`).attachTo(this.props.layer.findOne(`#${this.props.id}`).findOne(`#${this.props.id}`))}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to redraw a layer when you attach transformer:

```js
const node = this.props.layer.findOne(`#${this.props.id}`);
const transformer = this.props.layer.findOne(`#transform${this.props.id}`);
transformer.attachTo(node);
this.props.layer.batchDraw();
```